# JavaScript Internals 101: function and Function

Tags: javascript

```
>>> function () {}
SyntaxError

>>> f = function() {}
f = function() {}

>>> new function() {}
>>> Object

>>> new Function()
function anonymous() {}

>>> Function()
function anonymous() {}


>>> f = (function() { a = 10; return function() {console.log(a);} })();
>>> f()
10
undefined

>>> f = (function() { a = 10; return new Function('console.log(a)'); })();
>>> f()
undefined
```

Thus, I have two questions:

1. Why is the `Function` constructor returning a new function even without the `new` operator?
2. Are functions created with the `Function` constructors NOT closures?

Comment: On 2, yes, it's not a closure because the function definition string is evaluated in an isolated context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is the Function constructor returning a new function even without the new operator?

[Calling `Function()` is the same as calling `new Function()`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.1):

> When `Function` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initialises a new Function object. Thus the function call `Function(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new Function(…)` with the same arguments.

---

> Are functions created with the Function constructors NOT closures?

Yes, the scope of the function is set to the global environment, not to the scope of the lexical environment. See http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.2.1, step 11:

> 11. Return a new Function object created as specified in 13.2 passing *P* as the *FormalParameterList* and *body* as the *FunctionBody*. Pass in the Global Environment as the *Scope* parameter and *strict* as the *Strict* flag.

That means using the `Function` constructor is as if you declared a function in global scope, regarding the scope it can access (not regarding where the function is visible).

This is different from using function declarations/expressions, where the scope is based on the current exectution context (http://es5.github.com/#x13):

> 1. Let *funcEnv* be the result of calling NewDeclarativeEnvironment passing the running execution context’s Lexical Environment as the argument

Answer (score 1):

`Function` is the object used to implement `function`s, they are semantically the same underlying object.

However, a `function` is parsed at the same time as the script they belong to, whereas a `Function` body is parsed at instantiation time, which may explain why you get a difference of behaviour from your js interpreter.

see [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

1, functions can return objects, so it isn't absurd that `Function()` returns one. I'd double check the docs if you want to use it, because it is unusual enough that it might not work in all browsers.

2, correct.

Comment: `eval` is evaluated in the current lexical scope. Just try `(function() { var a = 'foo'; eval('alert(a);');}())`. So it actually does not behave like `eval`.